# arangodb-river-elasticsearch -- _mapping mismatch

Tags: arangodb, elasticsearch-plugin

When creating rivers for composed objects, the resulting `_mapping` is set with the complete nested object definition rather than String field. This causes the data import to fail because the object references are not "dereferenced".

E.g.

```
collection1: {name: "test", items: [collection2/123, collection2/124] }
collection1: {somefield: "test"}
```

The resulting `_mapping` after creating the river for those collections within a single index is:

```
collection1: {name: String, items: { properties: { somefield: String } } }.
```

Importing data fails with the following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping [items] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [collection1/123]
```

How can I either tell the arango db river to dereference the nested objects or set the mapping properly to work with references?

Comment: Is this still a problem? If not, did you manage to solve it and how?

Comment: No, rivers are now deprecated and I implemented my own custom solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rivers are now deprecated. I created a mixin for elasticsearch which updates the index when I save/update/delete objects (through my custom ODM).

Simply make yourself a wrapper around your data access layer with high level functions that also updates the ES index.

For example:

```
class Base(ArangoBase, es.Base):

def save(self):
    ret = ArangoBase.save(self)
    es.Base.save_es(self)
    return ret

def update(self):
    ret = ArangoBase.update(self)
    es.Base.save_es(self)
    return ret

def delete(self):
    ret = ArangoBase.delete(self)
    es.Base.delete_es(self)
    return ret

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class Base(object):
    _es = None
    _es_index = 'chopchop'
    _es_type = None

    def save_es(self):
        self._es.index(index=self._es_index, doc_type=self._es_type, body=self._doc(), id=self.id)

    def delete_es(self):
        self._es.delete(index=self._es_index, doc_type=self._es_type, id=self.id)
```